# elastic search will create cluster when mentioned cluster name in java or not?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The elastic search cluster name which we give in application.properties file. Will it create a new cluster name if it is not there in elasticsearch or what?

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration 
{
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name}")
    private String clusterName;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException 
    {
            String server = clusterNodes.split(":")[0];
            Integer port = Integer.parseInt(clusterNodes.split(":")[1]);
            Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
            client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(server), port));
            return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ? If this configuration information is used as client connection information I should think it will not create a new cluster.

Comment: Yeah, these are needed if you create direct connection and also requred if you create rest high level client for elastic search where these files will be internal and you just provide required key value in application.properties. I went through java doc of elastic search. But, found it is no help.

Comment: Settings.settingsBuilder() returns a Builder which has overloaded put(x, y) method. But, how it will work internally in elastic search, can't able to find. settingsBuilder() 
          Returns a builder(static ImmutableSettings.Builder) to be used in order to build settings.. Link -> http://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/0.14.4/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/ImmutableSettings.Builder.html

Comment: http://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/0.14.4/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/ImmutableSettings.html#settingsBuilder()